# Does Azure ADB2C App Registration for Web App requires App Key or not?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have checked many sample examples even by Microsoft on Azure ADB2C Authentication. All examples showing how to implement Azure ADB2C in Asp.Net Core Web App and Web Api together.

In Azure Portal, while registering Web App/Api, there is an option to generate App Key. My question is:

Do we really need to generate App Key and use it in Asp.Net Web App? I tried many samples and everything is fine but when I set invalid key in `AzureAdB2COptions`, its still working with no problem and not throwing any error. I removed the key from Azure Portal and its still working. Can anyone explain why?

The sample I used is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/)

Is this App Key for Web Api authentication?

Comment: Basically keys are required when your app uses an authentication flow that requires a key. So if you use authorization code flow from a back-end client, it'll require a key to exchange the codes for tokens. But if you use hybrid/implicit flow to get tokens, you won't need a key.

Comment: Hi, is my answer helpful? Anything else is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

As juunas mentioned, client secret is needed if your application exchanges a code for a token. It is used to prove Azure AD app's identity when requesting a token.

And [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) will not use a client secret to get the token.

Besides, if you use native/public client app, it would not be able to protect a secret. So generally we don't need client secret in native app.

I have tested the sample you shared. When I modify the `ClientSecret` in `appsettings.json` file and run this project, it will give an error requires me to correct the secret. You could have a quick test in an incognito window.